# NPOI C# populate table in Excel spreadsheet containing an XML Map

Tags: c#, excel, xml, npoi

Using C# and NPOI, I'm trying to import data into an existing Excel spreadsheet that contains a table and an XML Map as below.

[image]

When I try to save and close the spreadsheet at end of process I get a NullReferenceException as below:
[image]

The process runs successfully if I manually remove the XML Map prior to running the code, see sample output below:
[image]

However, the XML Map is crucial to the next step of the process, so I must work with the version that contains the XML Map. Why would the XML Map prevent the saving and closing of the file? Am I missing something? Do I have to somehow sync the XML Map with the table in the spreadsheet? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
using NPOI.POIFS.NIO;
using NPOI.SS.Formula.Functions;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.XWPF.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ExportSQLToExcel
{
    internal static class SQLToXLSXExporter
    {
        private const int HDRCOUNT = 3;

        internal static void ExportDataToXLSX(string? templateFileName, Int64 iRowsPerChunk)
        {
            if (File.Exists(templateFileName) == false)
            {
                throw (new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("File not found: {0}", templateFileName)));
            }

            string connectionString = @"Server=ROD-NUC; Database=UK1TST;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Server: {0}", builder.DataSource));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Database: {0}", builder.InitialCatalog));

            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sqlCon.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [GLPOST]", sqlCon);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            string workingFolder = @"D:\MyDocsFromRodNuc\Agentur Valle\Temp\";
            int iChunkNum = 1;
            string? chunkName = Path.Combine(workingFolder, string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(templateFileName), iChunkNum.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), Path.GetExtension(templateFileName)));
            string? templateFileNameTemp = Path.Combine(workingFolder, Path.GetFileName(templateFileName));

            // copy in the empty template
            File.Copy(templateFileName, templateFileNameTemp, true);

            XSSFWorkbook? templateWorkbook = null;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(templateFileNameTemp, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                templateWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            }
            string sheetName = "Gen. Journal Line";
            ISheet sheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheet(sheetName) ?? templateWorkbook.CreateSheet(sheetName);
            XSSFSheet XSheet = (XSSFSheet)sheet;
            var lstTables = XSheet.GetTables();
            XSSFTable? XTable = null;
            
            foreach (var item in lstTables)
            {
                XTable = (XSSFTable)item;
                break;
            }

            if (XTable == null)
            {
                throw (new ApplicationException(string.Format("No table found in spreadsheet: {0}", templateFileNameTemp)));
            }

            var inARefs = XTable.GetCellReferences();
            string sAreaRef = inARefs.FormatAsString();
            Debug.WriteLine(sAreaRef);

            // get the starting row number for the appending of extra rows
            // int iStartRow = XTable.EndRowIndex + 1;
            int iStartRow = XTable.EndRowIndex;

            // START OF: Build list of input field names from Sage DB Query
            string[] inputFieldNames = new string[reader.FieldCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                inputFieldNames[i] = reader.GetName(i);
            // END OF: Build list of input field names from Sage DB Query

            object[] inputFieldValues = new object[reader.FieldCount];

            int iRowCount = iStartRow;
            int iInputColNum = 0;
            int iOutputColNum = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (iRowCount == iRowsPerChunk)
                {
                    // save & close Excel Workbook (chunk)
                    using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(chunkName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        templateWorkbook.Write(fsOut, false);
                    }

                    iChunkNum++;
                    iRowCount = iStartRow;
                    chunkName = Path.Combine(workingFolder, string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(templateFileName), iChunkNum.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), Path.GetExtension(templateFileName)));

                    // copy in the empty template (again)
                    File.Copy(templateFileName, templateFileNameTemp, true);

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(templateFileNameTemp, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        templateWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
                    }
                }

                // read a row from the DB Query
                reader.GetValues(inputFieldValues);

                // Write row
                IRow dataRow = XSheet.CreateRow(iRowCount);

                string curInputFieldName = string.Empty;
                NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICell? cell = null;
                iInputColNum = -1;
                string sItem = string.Empty;

                // populate some fixed key field values.

                cell = dataRow.CreateCell(0); // Journal Template Name
                cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
                cell.SetCellValue("GENERAL");

                cell = dataRow.CreateCell(1); // Journal Batch Name
                cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
                cell.SetCellValue("DEFAULT");

                cell = dataRow.CreateCell(2); // Line No.
                cell.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);
                cell.SetCellValue(iRowCount);

                // for each input column
                foreach (var item in inputFieldValues)
                {
                    iInputColNum++;
                    curInputFieldName = inputFieldNames[iInputColNum];
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString()))
                    {
                        sItem = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        sItem = item.ToString().TrimEnd();
                    }

                    switch (curInputFieldName)
                    {
                        case "ACCTID": case "JNLDTLDESC":
                            iOutputColNum = GetOutputColumNumber(curInputFieldName);
                            cell = dataRow.CreateCell(iOutputColNum);
                            cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
                            cell.SetCellValue(sItem);
                            break;
                        case "DOCDATE":
                            iOutputColNum = GetOutputColumNumber(curInputFieldName);
                            cell = dataRow.CreateCell(iOutputColNum);
                            cell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
                            cell.SetCellValue(ProcessSageDate(sItem));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (iRowCount != iStartRow)
                {
                    sAreaRef = IncrementAreaRefRow(sAreaRef);
                }
                iRowCount++;
            }

            XTable.SetCellReferences(new NPOI.SS.Util.AreaReference(sAreaRef, NPOI.SS.SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007));
            XTable.UpdateReferences();

            using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(chunkName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                templateWorkbook.Write(fsOut);
                fsOut.Close();
                templateWorkbook.Close();
            }
            reader.Close();
            sqlCon.Close();

        }

        private static int GetOutputColumNumber(string curInputFieldName)
        {
            int iColumnNum = -1;
            switch (curInputFieldName.ToUpper())
            {
                case "ACCTID":
                    iColumnNum = 4;
                    break;
                case "JNLDTLDESC":
                    iColumnNum = 8;
                    break;
                case "DOCDATE":
                    iColumnNum = 5;
                    break;
            }
            return (iColumnNum);
        }

        private static string IncrementAreaRefRow(string sAreaRef)
        {
            // e.g. A3:M4 to A3:M5
            // &/OR:
            // e.g. A3:M14 to A3:M15
            // &/OR:
            // e.g. A3:M214 to A3:M215

            string[] parts = sAreaRef.Split(':');
            string endRef = parts[1];
            var sbEndRef = new StringBuilder();
            sbEndRef.Length = 0;
            CharEnumerator chEnum = endRef.GetEnumerator();
            while (chEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(chEnum.Current))
                {
                    sbEndRef.Append(chEnum.Current);
                }
            }
            // string sRowNum = sAreaRef.Substring(sAreaRef.Length - 1);
            int iRowNum = int.Parse(sbEndRef.ToString());
            iRowNum++;
            var sbAreaRefOut = new StringBuilder();
            sbAreaRefOut.Length = 0;
            sbAreaRefOut.Append(sAreaRef.Substring(0, sAreaRef.Length - sbEndRef.Length));
            sbAreaRefOut.Append(iRowNum.ToString());
            return (sbAreaRefOut.ToString());
        }

        private static string ProcessSageDate(string? inputDate)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDate) ) 
            {
                inputDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
            }

            // (e.g.) 20191014 to 14/10/2019
            StringBuilder lsb = new StringBuilder();
            lsb.Length = 0;
            lsb.Append(inputDate.Substring(inputDate.Length - 2)); // dd
            lsb.Append("/");
            lsb.Append(inputDate.Substring(4,2)); // mm
            lsb.Append("/");
            lsb.Append(inputDate.Substring(0, 4)); // yyyy

            return (lsb.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

When the erronious line is executed templateWorkbook is not null:

[image]

Comment: Where do you open the templateWorkbook?

Comment: I've edited in more of the code.

Comment: while (reader.Read()) when reader is null (or query from database is empty you never enter the while loop.  Then templateWorkbook is null because you never enter the while loop.  So when you execute templateWorkbook.Write(fsOut); the workbook is null.

Comment: Point taken, but the reader was not null, the query wasn't empty, the while loop is entered and therefore the templateWorkbook is not null. I've edited in the Locals window at time of error. The example above where the XML Map had been manually removed shows there is data to process.

Comment: The is an exception in the workbook indicating Ishidden and not implemented.  Does workbook contain any macros?  You workbook is not excel, but NPOI which is a third party library.  See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e87e7e16-0e01-43a8-a7bc-a0388c920d20/npoi-how-to-output-xlsx-file-from-custom-fileresult-writefile?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: It's a .xlsx file not .xlsm, so no macros. It contains a table & an XML Map. I was trying to determine if either of these affect the ability to populate the spreadsheet with NPOI third party library?

Comment: You are using XSSFWorkbook which uses XSSMap (not Xlmap).   See : https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFMap.html?force_isolation=true